# Assign permission to EKS cluter using IAM groups

Tags: amazon-eks, eks

Following this tutorial: https://archive.eksworkshop.com/beginner/091_iam-groups/test-cluster-access/ - Which I believe is missing the point it is trying to make, by assuming the role directly at the `Test EKS page`

I've created a role called `k8sAdmin` with the following policy/trust relations

```json
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Principal": {
                "AWS": "arn:aws:iam::ACCOUNT:root"
            },
            "Action": "sts:AssumeRole",
            "Condition": {}
        }
    ]
}
```

I've create a user group called `k8sAdministrators` with the following permission policy

```json
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "AllowAssumeOrganizationAccountRole",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": "sts:AssumeRole",
            "Resource": "arn:aws:iam::ACCOUNT:role/k8sAdmin"
        }
    ]
}
```

I've modified the `kube-system aws-auth` ConfigMap to assign permission to the `k8sAdmin` role.

```yaml
apiVersion: v1
data:
  mapRoles: |
    - groups:
      - system:bootstrappers
      - system:nodes
      rolearn: arn:aws:iam::ACCOUNT:role/eksctl-production-nodegrou-NodeInstanceRole
      username: system:node:{{EC2PrivateDNSName}}
    - groups:
      - system:masters
      rolearn: arn:aws:iam::ACCOUNT:role/k8sAdmin
      username: admin
  mapUsers: |
    []
```

When I assume the role directly, I can access the cluster.
But the goal is, to allow any user in the `k8sAdministrators` group to have access to the cluster, since the group has permission to assume role.

Does not work with the current config, group members are not authorized to access the cluster.